# SQL Server WHEN and subqueries

Tags: sql, sql-server

I needed help with a question and what would be the most clean way of doing this in SQL SERVER.

I am basically writing a query that checks if a customer number is inside another subquery then it should return the servicename for that customer number. This is my attempt and it is not working.

Do you guys have any suggestions?

```
 CASE  WHEN aa.cust_no in (SELECT Cust_no FROM #Tabl1) THEN (SELECT ServiceName  FROM #Tabl1) END AS Target
```

Comment: Your attempt is a statement that starts with `when`, which is not allowed in SQL.  Please edit your question and show the query.  Also, tag the question with the database you are using.

Comment: I understand however this is the only part that I need help with and that does not work. I cannot show all the code as it is over 300 lines of code.

Comment: Use something like CASE WHEN... THEN from A LEFT JOIN B

Comment: Show us a simplified version of your total query, including only the relevant portions. The current snippet is quite small.

Comment: Describe what you mean with "Not working"? You get the incorrect result? You get an error when executing the SQL statement?

Comment: The `THEN(SELECT ServiceName FROM #Tabl1)` seems very suspect as the subquery will probably return more than one row. That is not allowed as only one value is required there.

Comment: The Error I get with the above query is as follows:Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'THEN'. It seems like I cannot have a subquery in THEN.

Comment: That's correct.  You cannot have a subquery in THEN.  Show your whole query if you want help doing what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: Each customer number can only have one service so there will be no more than 1 row returning from the "tabl1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I get what you're trying to do, but you syntax needs to be changed.  You can try a `LEFT JOIN`.

This query will give you an idea of what your statement should look like

```
Select tabl1.ServiceName Target
From SomeTable aa
Left Join #Tabl1 tabl1
    On aa.cust_no = tabl1.Cust_no
```

If you want to put something else if a match is not found in `#Tabl1`, then you will need to use a `WHEN`, or a `COALESCE`.

`When tabl1.ServiceName Is NOT NULL Then tabl1.ServiceName Else 'Unknown Target' End`

OR

`Coalesce (tabl1.ServiceName, 'Unknown Target') Target`

Answer (score 1):

instead of `case` expression try select `ServiceName` in this way:

```
SELECT
   (SELECT TOP 1 ServiceName FROM #Tabl1 where Cust_no = aa.cust_no) AS Target
FROM ...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think ure missing one parameter look

```
CASE Expression
    WHEN Value1 THEN Result1
    WHEN Value2 THEN Result2
   ELSE Alternative
END
```

I hope this could help...

```
CASE  aa.cust_no 
WHEN (SELECT Cust_no FROM #Tabl1 WHERE #Tabl1.cust_no) THEN (SELECT ServiceName  FROM #Tabl1 WHERE #Tabl1.cust_no) 
  ELSE 'NO ServiceName'
END AS Target
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe this should get what you are looking for.

```
SELECT serviceName
FROM table_A
WHERE cust_no IN (
        SELECT cust_no
        FROM table_B
        );
```